# How to make text scroll parent to the recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have Textview on the top, Recyclerview in the middle, and one button on the button on the last.

I want to make when recyclerview scroll look like I put scroll view over my all element.

How to implement that?

Here is my xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/buslayout"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@color/bg_log"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="BUSINESS DIRECTRIES"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
        </LinearLayout>  

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/business_recycle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Load more"
            android:id="@+id/btnmore"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: @YLS I have Layout like my xml above: and if I scroll down it will hide the layout above the recyclerview, and if I scroll and nomore item it display the button below it.

Comment: you can use CoordinatorLayout and define scrolling behaviour for TextView and Botton

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayoutandroid:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/buslayout"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#fffffff"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="BUSINESS DIRECTRIES"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>



<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/business_recycle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Load more"
    android:id="@+id/btnmore"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I use the scrollview to cover my xml I can't Do with onscroll event. so that why I removed it.